# Ternary If that includes a functions result

Tags: java, conditional-operator

I was just wondering if there's a more efficient way to do something along the lines of this in Java.

Just going to use this dummy function as an example

```
static int getDivision(int number, int divider) {
    if(divider == 0) { return -1; }
    return (number / divider);
}
```

If I have a ternary operator that is checking the result of that function like the below

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    int result;

    result = getDivision(2, 0);
    System.out.println (
        result == -1 ? "No" : result
    );

}
```

I have to create a variable to store the result, otherwise I can do it like this

```
    System.out.println (
        getDivision(2, 0) == -1 ? "No" : getDivision(2, 0)
    );
```

But I have to call the function twice which is even worse. Is it possible to use the ternary operator but include the result of a function in the conditions?

```
    System.out.println (
        getDivision(2, 0) == -1 ? "No" : /*returned result*/
    );
```

Comment: No, there's no way to do that in a single expression, other than by creating a method that you invoke like: `myMethodUsingConditionalExpression(getDivision(2, 0))`.

Comment: Just write `int result = getDivision(2, 0); System.out.println(result == -1 ? "No" : result);`. There is no efficiency concern here, so readability matters most.

Comment: `for (int result = getDivision(2, 0), iterations = 0; iterations < 1; System.out.println(result == -1 ? "No" : result, iterations++);` (Not being serious).

Comment: Dang, that's a bummer but thanks a bunch, I guess I'll stick with the current one

Comment: In your ternary expression, you are returning either a String or an int. This won't work.

Comment: @NomadMaker wouldn't it just box the `int`? `Object obj = true ? 1 : "";` is fine.

Comment: The return type for the question are irrelevant, I'm more concerned with the general concept

Comment: This site isn't much on general concept, but rather specific answers for specific questions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using `Optional`, you can represent a real result as well as indicate that no result is present:

```
static Optional<Integer> getDivision(int number, int divider) {
    return divider == 0 ? Optional.empty() : Optional.of(number / divider);
}
```

Usage:

```
Optional<Integer> result = getDivision(2, 0);
System.out.println(result.map(String::valueOf).orElse("No"));
```

Or if you only want to further process the result when it is present:

```
result.ifPresent( value -> ...);
```

EDIT: the value `-1` is also a valid outcome of some divisions, which works fine with the `Optional` as well, compared to the original approach:

```
Optional<Integer> result = getDivision(-5, 5);
```

Comment: This is, of course, better than returning -1, which is an otherwise valid result from the division. You could alternatively use `OptionalInt`.

Comment: It's actually way better, as `-1` can be a valid result of a division (see edited answer) :)